# How to understand the format of a netCDF file

Tags: metpy

I am trying to generate a graph of the spatial average (i.e. 2x2 degrees) wave height and wind speed of each sea for various seas for a period of 5 years with yearly or monthly time interval (i.e. North/South Atlantic, Pacific, Arabic sea, North sea, Baltic sea, Mediterranean sea etc.). Is there a guide somewhere out there on how to do this?

Also i am trying to identify whether the wind speed is the surface wind speed or the wind at 10m above the sea surface. I am aware that in depends on the means of observation (i.e. if it is a ship of buoy). Is there an explanation from NOAA or another organization of the how the data are formatted. The only document that i found was https://icoads.noaa.gov/e-doc/imma/R3.0-imma1_short.pdf.

Thank you in advance.

Kind Regards
George

Comment: Hello George, Can you please share your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing from a Gitter conversation about this question, the simplest solution looks like:

```
ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature')
ds_proc = ds.sel(lat=slice(90, 0), lon=slice(200, 250)).groupby('time.month').mean('time').mean(['lat', 'lon']))
ds_proc['air'].plot()
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

If you want to include a full geographic map, we recommend using [Cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/). As far as your metadata goes, you'll have to look at the attributes associated with the wind variable in your file. I don't see anything specific in the ICOADS file you provided. If you use xarray, it could be something like:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('filename.nc')
print(ds['wind_variable'].attrs)
```